# Get RegionManager in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation, prism

In my project I use Prism for the Views and ViewModels. I now want to load another view into a UserControl in the MainWindowView. I read I can do this with this:

`_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", typeof(View));`

But unfortunately I have no idea how to get to the instance of `IRegionManger` in my ViewModel. In all examples I found, other variables are used, but it is not shown where they come from.

This is my View:

```
<Window x:Class="PortfolioVisualizer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PortfolioVisualizer"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="15*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
            <Button Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="AddAssetView">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image/>
                    <Label Content="Add Asset"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="ConfigView">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image/>
                    <Label Content="Settings"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion"/>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly IRegionManager _RegionManager;

        public DelegateCommand<string> NavigateCommand;
        

        public MainWindowViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
        {
            _RegionManager = regionManager;
            NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(ExecuteNavigateCommand);
            _RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", typeof(DashboardView));
        }

        private void ExecuteNavigateCommand(string viewName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(viewName))
                return;

            _RegionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", viewName);
        }
    }
```

This is the ViewModdelBase

```
public class ViewModelBase : BindableBase
    {
        public ViewModelBase()
        {
        
        }
    }
```

(I know that the ViewModelBase is just superfluous, but there is something to come later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the container inject the region manager like any other dependency:

```
internal class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel( IRegionManager regionManager )
    {
        regionManager.DoSomeStuff(); // or just put it into a field for later use
    }
}
```

Note that this only works automatically, if you don't manually `new` the view model either in code or in xaml. Instead, create it with a factory that is itself injected (e.g. `Func<MyViewModel> myViewModelFactory`) if you go view model-first (recommended most of the time), or use Prism's `ViewModelLocator` to have it created as data context if you go view-first.

Comment: How does it look like in the XAML? Do I have to specify any paramter there?

Comment: @arne `ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel=true` suffices - given your views are in the `Views` namespace and the view models in `ViewModels` and they have a common base name, e.g. `MySpecialView` and `MySpecialViewModel`. You can also register view/view model pairs with the view model provider if you don't like the convention approach (although it's perfectly fine).

Comment: When I do this I get an exception because the constructor of the ViewModel cannot get parameters

Comment: This is the exception: ```MissingMethodException: Cannot dynamically create an instance of type 'PortfolioVisualizer.MainWindowViewModel'. Reason: No parameterless constructor defined.```

Comment: How do you create the view model? The view model locator will use the container and supply all parameters. If you manually call your constructor, you have to provide them yourself.

Comment: I have posted my source code in my question

Comment: @arne the xaml you posted is only the opening tag - we're not seeing if there's `<Window.DataContext>` around there, for example. `<viewModels:MainWindowViewModel/>` is a constructor call, too. Also note that views have to reside in a `Views` namespace and view models in `ViewModels` so that the default convention works.

Comment: So I have now posted the entire ViewModel and View. Thanks for helping me so patiently

Comment: You create the `MainWindow` with `Resolve<MainWindow>()`? Then, this _should_ work with the default `PrismApplication`s. Is `ConfigureViewModelLocator` called in your setup, i.e. is a break point hit there?

Comment: I do not know what you mean. I do not use any of them.

Comment: If `ConfigureViewModelLocator` is not called and you don't set the view model factory manually, Prism uses `Activator.CreateInstance` by default, which cannot inject anything and would explain the exception you're witnessing. See the code [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/d8b8a7de2b10c528e46caba309db51748d9106a0/src/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/PrismInitializationExtensions.cs#L24). Which container, prism application, bootstrapper etc. do you use?

Comment: Now I got it. Thank you so much